# Codeigniter HMVC and calling a view from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, dynamic-forms, hmvc

New to HMVC in Codeigniter.

Dynamic form allows new "segments" to be created when a user clicks a link.

Currently the segment html & php is in module/view/segment_view.php.  The view requires dynamic php variables as well.

How can I "load the view" using jQuery? I understand I can't directly load a view from jQuery but am lost on how to structure the controller for an AJAX call.  Seems this may not be a strength of Codeigniter?

**EDIT:**
The "segment" is inside a form.  The form always has 1 segment.  jQuery can add more segments.  Each segment requires php arrays for form inputs and validation.

Here is a pared down version of the form_view file

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$number_of_segments; $i++) {

    $data['location'] = array(
        'name'  =>  "segment[$i][location]",
        'value' =>  set_value("segment[$i][location]"),
        'maxlength' =>  '255',
        'size'  =>  '30'
    );  
 ?>
    <div class="area">
        <div class="row"><h2>Segment <?php echo $i;?></h2></div>

        <?php 
        $this->load->view('module/segment_view', $data);
        ?>

    </div> <!--/div class="area"-->
<?php
}    //end for
?>
```

OK, so this isn't really separating application logic from presentation, now is it?  Ha ha.  So what is the best way to structure this so the code is HMVC and can be accessed from a php controller/view as well as jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call view files directly by URL, you need to call a controller method that loads the view.

If you want to do some "ajax only" stuff, you may use this function:

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) // Do ajax stuff
```

Examples would be loading view fragments or json. You don't have to make "ajax only" methods in your controller, you can use this function from within your existing controller methods to do something different if it's an ajax request.

Not sure if this resolves anything for you, provide some code and more context of what you're trying to do and we can give you some clearer advice.

Comment: thanks and I believe that `is_ajax_request` is what I am looking for but I am still trying to fully grasp the proper way to implement complex HMVC.  Please check my edits if you can.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ChristopherIckes: I'm sorry to admit, but after seeing your edit I still can't figure out what you're trying to do, or what you're having issues with. There's really nothing at all related to HMVC or jQuery as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ha ha, that's true!  But `is_ajax_request()` was the answer.  I separated the above question in controller & view and removed the view logic.  Now I can request the pieces I need using `is_ajax_request()`.  Works like a charm now that the idea is developed and the code is HMVC, not gobbledy gook.  Thanks.